# Loading AVRO from Bucket via CLI into BigQuery with Date partition

Tags: google-bigquery, avro

I'm trying to import data into BigQuery via AVRO with a Date partition. When importing via the cli an error is related to a partitioned date has to be a Date or Timestamp but it is getting an Integer.

Given an AVRO file similar to the one below:

```
{
  "namespace": "test_namespace",
  "name": "test_name",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    { 
      "name": "partition_date",
      "type": "int",
      "logicalType": "date"
    },
    {
      "name": "unique_id",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "value",
      "type": "double"
    }
}
```

I am then using the following commands through the CLI to try and create a new table

```
bg load \
--replace \
--source_format=AVRO \
--use_avro_logical_types=True \
--time_partitioning_field partition_date \
--clustering_fields unique_id \
mydataset.mytable \
gs://mybucket/mydata.avro
```

The expectation is that a new table that is partitioned on the Date column "partition_date" and then clustered by "unique_id".

Edit: Please see the error below

```
The field specified for the time partition can only be of type TIMESTAMP or DATE. The type found is: INTEGER.
```

The exact command I am using is as follows:

```
bq load --replace --source_format=AVRO --use_avro_logical_types=True --time_partitioning_field "partition_date" --clustering_fields "unique_id" BQ_DATASET BUCKET_URI
```

This is the AVRO schema that I am using

```
{
    "namespace": "example.avro",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "Test",
    "fields": [
        { "name": "partition_date", "type": "int", "logicalType": "date" },
        { "name": "unique_id", "type": "string"},
        { "name": "value", "type": "float" }
   ]
}
```

It's worth noting that this is an old Google Project (about 2 - 3 years old) if that is any relevance.

I'm also on windows 10 with the latest Google SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google finally got back to me (7 months later). In this time I no longer have access to the initial project that I had issues with. However I'm documenting a successful example for those finding this later with a new project.

Following a comment from the issue tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905894#comment87) I found that I was not using a complex type for the logical date field.

So this:

```
{ 
  "name": "partition_date",
  "type": "int",
  "logicalType": "date"
}
```

Should have been written like this (Note the nested complex object for type):

```
{ 
  "name": "partition_date",
  "type": {
    "type": "int",
    "logicalType": "date"
  }
}
```

Although the [avro specification](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/spec.html#Date) lists a date as the number of days from the unix epoch (1 Jan 1970) I had to write the partition_date as `datetime.date(1970, 1, 1)` instead of just `0`.

The commands (bq) were unchanged from the original post.

As stated I don't know if this would have fixed my issue with the original project but hopefully this helps the next person.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this @michaelgambold. It saved me a ton of time.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't received any error message doing the same loading operation, generating equal AVRO data schema and using the desired Bigdata sink table structure.

According to GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-avro) you've used `--use_avro_logical_types=True` flag along `bq` command-line properly propagating [conversion](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-avro#logical_types) data types, keeping `DATA` Avro logical type be translated to the equivalent [Date](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#date_type) type in Bigquery.

You can refer to my Bigquery table schema, validating table structure on your side, as you haven't provided table structure and error message itself I can't suggest more so far:

```
$ bq show --project_id=<Project_ID>  <Dataset>.<Table>
Table <Project_ID>:<Dataset>.<Table>

   Last modified            Schema            Total Rows   Total Bytes   Expiration        Time Partitioning        Clustered Fields   Labels
 ----------------- ------------------------- ------------ ------------- ------------ ----------------------------- ------------------ --------
  22 Apr 12:03:57   |- partition_date: date   3            66                         DAY (field: partition_date)   unique_id
                    |- unique_id: string
                    |- value: float
```

I have used `FLOAT` type for `value` to plainly convert AVRO `DOUBLE` data type as per recommendations [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-avro#primitive_types).

`bq` CLI version:

```
$ bq version
This is BigQuery CLI 2.0.56
```

Feel free to expand the origin question with more specific information on the issue you're hitting, further assisting more accurately with the solution.

**UPDATE:**

I've checked information provided, but I'm still confused with the error you're getting. Apparently I see that in your case flag `use_avro_logical_types=True` does not perform logical type conversion. However I've found this PIT feature [request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905894) where people are asking to "whitelist" their projects in order to afford AVRO logicaltype functionality, i.e. this [comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905894#comment71). Since this feature have been rolled out to globe community, it might be the oversight that some GCP projects are not enabled to use it.

Comment: I've written some notes to my answer, pls check them.

Comment: Thanks for that, It's been frustrating when things don't work as per documentation (Although Google's documentation is very.....brief). I tried to look at the links you sent and I could not log in with my google credentials. It took me to a Google corp login with "moma inside google" on it

Comment: I've replaced wrong links, sorry for that, pls check out.

Comment: You might also consider to raise a personal issue within a separate [PIT](https://issuetracker.google.com) thread. Feel free to share any further inspirations here.

Comment: If you find my answer helpful, kindly consider [accept/up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) vote my answer, giving opportunity for the next contributors get support in their research on the relevant topic.

Comment: I will as soon as I get some feedback from Google. I added a comment [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905894#comment84) but got no traction. So I have created a new [PIT](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155315623)